# Display jsonp query results with gwt uibinder

Tags: gwt, jsonp, uibinder

I use GWT UiBinder to create the view of a GWT app. There is a dynamic part of the view where I need to make a jsonp query for external server and display the String results from jsonp query into the gwt view page.

Is there a clever way to tell the uibinder xml file how to display these dynamic jsonp results?

it is basically inserting a list of Hyperlinks in the dynamic part of view. how can we do it with uibinder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You should retrieve this string in your app, and inject it in your view.

You can create a custom widget that does this, and then you can use this widget in Ui:Binder, but you should consider how it would affect automated testing of your app.

Comment: you mean by injecting to view doing this programmatically? can you give an example how to inject the hyperlinks to my view by coding this in the view class?

Comment: If your string contains proper HTML, you can add an HTML widget to your Ui:Binder, and then, when you retrieve your string, set this widget's HTML using your string.